# PostgreSQL Table Partition based on number of records

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I am new to PostgreSQL table partitioning. I want create partition tables at the run time based on number of record parent table will contain. Suppose I have 2M records in parent table then I should be able to create 2 partition tables of 1M each. In my case Parent Table is UNLOGGED Table and contains few columns as primary key. I was trying create and select query and delete on parent table, but delete seems to be slowing down the whole process. Is there any better way to do it?

P.S - I don't have access to PostgreSQL's admin tools

Comment: For just 2 million rows, there is hardly any need to partition at all. What you are looking for is called "hash partitioning" - but that's currently not available in Postgres. The upcoming Postgres 11 (to be released in Q4 2018) will support that though

Comment: With regard to, "delete seems to be slowing down the whole process", do you have a foreign key to the parent table, and if so have you created an index on the foreign key columns?

Comment: The parent table contains only primary key. @DavidAldridge

Comment: 2 million is just example @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @RutujRashinkar And does the child table contain a foreign key to the parent table? Are the foreign key columns covered by an index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding indexes on newly created partition table helped to delete millions of records in 2-5s. That solved my Table Partitioning Problem.